# can't == be used instead of unary & to check if two values are equal

Tags: java, boolean, bit-manipulation, operator-keyword

Recently I came across a code snippet in a book which sets a `Boolean` value to a field like this

the input `identifier` is a `List` of `String`s

```
if (identifier.size() >= 2) {
    int c = Integer.parseInt(identifier.get(1));
    bulk = (c & 4) == 4;
    hazardous = (c & 2) == 2;
    toxic = (c & 1) == 1;
}
```

what is the need for unary & operators here?Can't this be done using a simple 
`c==4` etc instead of `(c & 4)== 4` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, this is a bitwise operation.

Imagine `c=7`. In that case all conditions would be true.

```
c = 7;
bulk = (c & 4) == 4; // true
hazardous = (c & 2) == 2; //true
toxic = (c & 1) == 1; //true
```

In binary, you'd have this:

```
c = 0111; //4-bit to simplify output
bulk = (c & 0100) == 0100; //
hazardous = (c & 0010) == 0010; //true
toxic = (c & 0001) == 0001; //true
```

Due to bitwise AND (&) you get `0111 & 0010 = 0010` etc.

Answer (score 2):

This is added for [bit masking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29)

if 
c =3 then also it will be considered as toxic with this

```
 toxic = (c & 1) == 1;
```

if you write

```
 toxic = c  == 1;
```

then it would be stcict 1 check

Answer (score 1):

The variable `c` is clearly a [bitmask](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mask_%28computing%29). The effect of doing the bitwise `&` is mask off the other bits, leaving just the one bit still set. For example, this statement:

```
    bulk = (c & 4) == 4;
```

tests if bit 2 of `c` is set (and doesn't care about the other bits) - bit 2 being the `1` bit in this byte: `00000100`

Answer (score 1):

c == 4 checks if c equals 4, meaning the binary form of c is 000...00100. (c & 4) == 4 if the binary form of c is the following xxx...xx1xx.